# Player Health persists through multiple scenes using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a 2d platformer, where the player is given 9 lives on start, and loses a life everytime they hit an obstacle.

The GameManager script stores and displays the health and the Entity script updates the health in GameManager if the player loses a life.

If the player loses a life, they can respawn in that level.

On completion of a level, the player goes to a new scene "Level Complete", where they can choose to continue to the next level or quit the game.

However, when the player continues to the next level, the currentHealth variable does not persist and resets to 0.

I know WHY this problem is occurring, but I do not know how to fix it.
currentHealth is not being called anywhere in LevelComplete, so on Start in GameManager, it has lost the value of currentHealth.

I can't call GameManager on LevelComplete because it will spawn the player. So I'm not sure how to pass the variable.
Here are my scripts.

### Game Manager

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject player;
    private GameCamera cam;
    private GameObject currentPlayer;
    private Vector3 checkpoint;

    public Text livesText;
    private Entity livesCount;
    public static int startHealth = 9;
    public int currentHealth;
    public bool playerDeath = false;

    public static int levelCount = 2;
    public static int currentLevel = 1;

    void Start () {
        cam = GetComponent<GameCamera> ();
        livesText.text = currentHealth.ToString ();

        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Spawn")){
            checkpoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Spawn").transform.position;
        }

        SpawnPlayer (checkpoint);
    }

    private void SpawnPlayer(Vector3 spawnPos) {
        currentPlayer = Instantiate (player, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        cam.setTarget(currentPlayer.transform);
    }

    public void Update(){
        if(!currentPlayer){
            if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Respawn")) {
                playerDeath = false;
                SpawnPlayer (checkpoint);
            }
        }
        if (playerDeath) {
            Destroy (currentPlayer);
        }
        if (currentPlayer) {
            currentHealth = currentPlayer.GetComponent<Entity> ().GetHealth ();
        }
        livesText.text = currentHealth.ToString ();
    }

    public void SetCheckPoint(Vector3 cp){
        checkpoint = cp;
    }

    public void EndLevel(){
        if(currentLevel < levelCount){
            currentLevel++;
            Application.LoadLevel("Level Complete");
        }
        else{
            Application.LoadLevel("Game Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

### Entity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Entity : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int currHealth;
    private int checkHealth; //Make sure 0 < health < 9

    public void ModifyHealth(int amount){
        checkHealth = currHealth + amount;

        if (checkHealth >= 9) {
            currHealth = 9; //Health can't be greater than 9
        }
        else if(checkHealth <= 0){
            Die (); //End game if health is less than or equal to 0
        }
        else{
            currHealth = checkHealth; //Otherwise, update Health
        }
    }

    public int GetHealth(){
        return currHealth;
    }

    public void SetHealth(int currentHealth){
        currHealth = currentHealth;
    }

    public void Die(){
        Application.LoadLevel ("Game Over");
    }
}
```

### Level Complete

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour {
    public GUISkin gSkin;

    void OnGUI(){
        GUI.skin = gSkin;

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width/2) - Screen.width *0.15f,Screen.height/2 - Screen.height *0.05f,Screen.width*0.3f,Screen.height*0.1f),"Next Level")){
            Application.LoadLevel ("Level 2");
        }
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width/2) - Screen.width *0.15f,Screen.height/2 + 20.0f,Screen.width*0.3f,Screen.height*0.1f),"Quit")){
            Application.Quit ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you not just declare a static var to simply keep track? im pretty sure this will allow you to keep persistence through your scenes and be available to your other scripts

Comment: @StevenSmith this type of approach tends to lead to hard-to-find bugs.  Singletons made testing difficult, they violate the SRP, and they can have strange side effects if you are not paying incredibly close attention.

Comment: true singletons are a pain in the butt to test but still usable, i can only think of 2 alternative ways, 1 maybe setting a hidden gameobject in the 1st scene then apply a script to it and make sure not to destroy it when loading a new scene (i feel thats the pretty much same method as a static declaration)  Or maybe some outside persistence to a simple text file as its data, this would open up some doors for other variables to be stored also, only problem is increased complexity, not sure if the OP would want to do that, what would you recommend David? iether or non of the above?

Comment: oh wait try looking at this, player pref, forgot about this, might help you.
http://pfonseca.com/how-to-persist-simple-data-on-unity/

Comment: I used a static variable, and this seemed to work fine when I removed the Level Complete scene.